# xpath usage while scraping data using lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to write a python script to scrape data from a webpage. However, I am not able to figure out correct usage of xpath to retrieve value. Please help me in fixing this.

The url in question is https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&strike=10400.00&type=CE&expiry=30NOV2017

I am trying to get value of VWAP value ,which at present is 27.16(this value changes every business day.) When is inspect the value in Chrome, I get the following xpath for required value

```
<span id="vwap">27.16</span>
```

As per online tutorial , I wrote following python script

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&strike=10400.00&type=CE&expiry=30NOV2017')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
vwap = tree.xpath('//span[@id="vwap"]/text()')
print(vwap)
```

But when i execute this command, I get following output

```
[]
```

instead of

```
27.16
```

I have also tried replacing xpath line to following as per some other answer on stackoverflow, but still I am not getting the correct output.

```
vwap = tree.xpath('//*[@id="vwap"]/text()')
```

Please let me know what to put inside xpath so that I get correct value inside vwap variable.

Any other solutions(other than lxml) are also welcome.

Comment: Create a [mcve] within your question.  Questions dependent on external links will be closed as their value to future readers shouldn't depend upon a link that could break.

Comment: I have removed the tutorial link but I cannot remove the external link to website www.nseindia.com as I want to solve issue for that page itself. I am able to run the sample code available with online tutorials but not able to adapt it to external website(nseindia.com) where I want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to check page source as it initially appears required node will look like

```
<li><a style="color: #000000;" title="VWAP">VWAP</a> <span id="vwap"></span></li>
```

while this is how it appears after JavaScript executed

```
<li><a style="color: #000000;" title="VWAP">VWAP</a> <span id="vwap">27.16</span></li>
```

Note that there is no text content in first HTML sample

It seem that values comes from below node

```
<div id="responseDiv" style="display:none">
{"valid":"true","isinCode":null,"lastUpdateTime":"29-NOV-2017 15:30:30","ocLink":"\/marketinfo\/sym_map\/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2","tradedDate":"29NOV2017","data":[{"change":"-17.80","sellPrice1":"13.80","buyQuantity3":"450","sellPrice2":"13.85","buyQuantity4":"150","buyQuantity1":"13,725","ltp":"-243019.52","buyQuantity2":"6,225","sellPrice5":"14.00","sellPrice3":"13.90","buyQuantity5":"450","sellPrice4":"13.95","underlying":"NIFTY","bestSell":"-2,41,672.50","annualisedVolatility":"9.44","optionType":"CE","prevClose":"31.10","pChange":"-57.23","lastPrice":"13.30","lowPrice":"11.00","strikePrice":"10400.00","premiumTurnover":"11,707.33","numberOfContractsTraded":"5,74,734","underlyingValue":"10,361.30","openInterest":"58,96,350","impliedVolatility":"12.73","vwap":"27.16","totalBuyQuantity":"10,49,850","openPrice":"35.10","closePrice":"17.85","bestBuy":"-2,43,852.25","changeinOpenInterest":"1,60,800","clientWisePositionLimits":"30517526","totalSellQuantity":"11,07,825","dailyVolatility":"0.49","sellQuantity5":"19,800","marketLot":"75","expiryDate":"30NOV2017","marketWidePositionLimits":"-","sellQuantity2":"75","sellQuantity1":"3,825","buyPrice1":"13.00","sellQuantity4":"900","buyPrice2":"12.90","sellQuantity3":"2,025","buyPrice4":"12.75","buyPrice3":"12.80","buyPrice5":"12.65","turnoverinRsLakhs":"44,94,632.53","pchangeinOpenInterest":"2.80","settlementPrice":"-","instrumentType":"OPTIDX","highPrice":"40.85"}],"companyName":"Nifty 50","eqLink":""}
</div>
```

so the code that you might need is

```
import json

vwap = json.loads(tree.xpath('//div[@id="responseDiv"]/text()')[0].strip())['data'][0]['vwap']
```

Comment: Thank you Andersson for the solution. I was using Inspect button with chrome which showed the final populated value after JavaScript executed. Since I am learning about this stuff, would you suggest to look at page source for future issue or are there some readily available tools which you use on a regular basis.

Comment: In Chrome you can do CTRL+U to open initial page source (before JavaScript executed). Then you can simply do CTRL+F and enter, for example, id of required element to find it on page